# Comparing Dates fields in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables. `TableA` has a column called `Jan2018`. This is a calculation which means that I have filled this Column based on some condition in the `TableA`. For each row in `TableA`, I have filled column `Jan2018` with the value `01/01/2018`.

The column type is set as Date and format is (M/d/yyyy). In `TableB` I have a date column `Stop_Date` which is also formatted as (M/d/yyyy). I want to count the number of rows in `TableA` where `Jan2018` matches the value in `TableB[Stop_Date]`. This count will be stored as a value in a new column in `TableB`. I have tried `COUNTX`, `COUNTAX` functions but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the forum @WAkram. Please see if below DAX work:

```
TCount =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( TableA ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( TableA ), TableA[Jan2018] = TableB[Stop_Date] )
)
```

Post error message or result if it do not work.

Thanks

Comment: It worked! In fact I added more conditions in the the FILTER using &&. Thanks for your help.